# Index A Matrix Using A Vector of Indices in Armadillo LIbrary

Tags: c++, armadillo, matrix-indexing

I'm using the Armadillo Cpp code for matrix algebra. I have an Eigenvector matrix `E` that I want to sort by its eigenvalues in a vector `d`.

```
mat E;
vec d;
eig_sym(d,E,Rxx);


// Sort indices of eignen values / vectors
// based on decreasing real part of eigen values.
uvec order = sort_index(-d);

// Extract top eigen vectors.
E = E(span::all,order(1,nb_sources));
```

I couldn't find anything related to this kind of indexing in the documentation. Indexing using a vector is such a common requirement that I'd be surprised if it isn't present in Armadillo.

What is the proper way to do this in Armadillo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is

```
E = E.cols(order(span(0,nb_sources-1)));
```

Comment: Thanks! this does the job. How can I perform this type of indexing in both dimesnions?

Comment: See 'non-contiguous views' at http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat